# Установка свойства Id при заполнении БД начальными данными в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Можно ли как то настроить чтобы для поля ID значения генерировались автоматически при добавлении их в БД? Потому что пытаясь создать первую миграцию выдает ошибку:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Sensor' cannot be added because a non-zero value is required for property 'Id'. Consider providing a negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data.

#### Класс сущности:

```
public class Sensor
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
     public double Price { get; set; }
     public string? Description { get; set; }
 }
```

#### Инициализация БД начальными данными.

```
public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder builder) {
    builder.Entity<Sensor>().HasData(
        new Sensor { Name = "K1", Price = 52, Description = "С засыпкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "К1У", Price = 52, Description = "С засыпкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "K2", Price = 52, Description = "С засыпкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "K2.1", Price = 52, Description = "С засыпкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "K3", Price = 52, Description = "С засыпкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "K4", Price = 52, Description = "С засыпкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "K5", Price = 52, Description = "С засыпкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "К1И", Price = 52, Description = "С засыпкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "Кл1-1", Price = 52, Description = "С клеемной головкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "Кл1-2", Price = 52, Description = "С клеемной головкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "Кл1-3", Price = 52, Description = "С клеемной головкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "Кл4-1", Price = 52, Description = "С клеемной головкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "Кл2-2", Price = 58, Description = "С клеемной головкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "Кл3-1", Price = 48, Description = "С клеемной головкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "Кл1-3", Price = 52, Description = "С клеемной головкой" },
        new Sensor { Name = "Рт-3", Price = 52, Description = "Другие" },
        new Sensor { Name = "Рт-4", Price = 52, Description = "Другие" },
        new Sensor { Name = "Рт-5", Price = 52, Description = "Другие" },
        new Sensor { Name = "It-7", Price = 37, Description = "Другие" });

}
```

Comment: [Документация > Ограничения](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#:~:text=%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте 2 атрибута к свойству Id. Атрибут DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity каждый раз будет увеличивать значение на 1.

```
public class Sensor
{
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
       public double Price { get; set; }
       public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Все та же ошибка. "The seed entity for entity type 'Sensor' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'Id'."

Comment: @Nik25 вы бд пересоздали?

Comment: Да пересоздал, все та же проблема.

Comment: @Nik25 способ выше работает на обычное добавление/миграцию, но не на первичное(которое при создании бд) и вы думаю вызываете ваш метод Seed в OnModelCreating Context'а. Там нужно указывать Id. Возможно и там есть способы его не указывать, но увы я такого не знаю(.

Comment: @Nik25 Меня игнорировать не надо, я дал под вопросом ссылку на документацию, где прямым текстом написано в ограничениях, что указывать ID надо **обязательно**. Внимательней будьте.

Comment: @xellan При чем тут это все? Вы контекст вопроса уловили? Речь не про `db.Table.Add(new("Вася", 13)); db.SaveChanges()` которая за вас проставляет все, речь про **миграцию**, первоначальные данные которые должна внести **миграция**, так называемое "Data Seeding", то есть процесс, который происходит **ДО** всех атрибутов и прочих приблуд EF, а значит у них есть ограничения, и одно из них - **Данные должны быть заполнены все, включая ID**. Внимательней будьте, прошу... Ну а что касается атрибутов, в 90% случаев они не нужны, EF весьма умная и понимает что такое ключ.